# Dot separated value is inserted instead of comma in asp

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, ms-access

I'm kinda "fresh" in classic ASP and I have the following insert SQL query in classic ASP and i can't make it insert comma separated value from a CSV file in MS Access database, but instead it will convert it in dot separated thousand value.

E.g.: 
**price = "49,55"**

```
insert_sql = "INSERT INTO table (price) VALUES ('" & price & "')
DataConn.execute(insert_sql)
```

I tried to convert it like:

```
CDbl(price) or FormatNumber(price)
```

but what i get after all is ***4.955,00***.

I've tried changing localization, but i still have the same problem.

P.S.: I am aware of the fact that the above code is SQL Injection vulnerable, but for now i'm trying to understand what's wrong, or what do i forget.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is with locale. You can use comma as decimal separator in *presentation* but not in code. Inside the code decimal values look like **49.55**.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev I've tried changing Locale with **Session.LCID** in header, but i still have the same problem.

Comment: make sure that your generated SQL query looks like this `INSERT INTO table (price) VALUES (49.55)`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Ok the way it worked was using the function **Replace([variable], ",", ".")** and everything's fine! 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use **Str** to force a **dot** as the decimal separator:

```
insert_sql = "INSERT INTO table (price) VALUES (" & Str(price) & ")"
```

Then, for display of the price, apply any format you prefer.